# Cypress constants/variable in custom command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following bit of code for a cypress custom command, which I use to generate a user session cookie:

```
   Cypress.Commands.add('getSession', (email, password) => {
        return cy.request({
            url: 'xxx',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                email,
                password,
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            let body = (response.body);
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            cy.log('Id - ' + body.customerId);

            let session = "SESSIONID=" + body.Cookies.SESSIONID + ";" ...
            cy.log('raw session data - ' + session)

            //Base64 encode
            cy.writeFile('tmp/rawStr.txt', session, 'utf8');
            cy.readFile('tmp/rawStr.txt', 'base64').then((cookie) => {
                cy.log('base64 string - ' + cookie);
            });
        })
    });
```

I would like to re-use the value in 'cookie' in another custom command, but whenever I run the test it says cookie is undefined. All I'm doing in that test is creating a Cookie header which includes the base64 string I create in the above step.

The custom command in question looks like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createThing', (name) => {
        return cy.request({
            url: 'xxx',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Cookie' : 'client_token=' + cookie,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                'name' : name
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            let body = (response.body);
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            cy.log(body);
        });
    });
```

How do I get the custom commands to share that cookie value?

My spec file calls the custom commands like so:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

    describe('deletes a user thing', function() {
      it('create a thing via the api', function() {
        cy.getSession('xxxx', 'xxxxx')
        cy.createThing('thing')
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to split into 2 custom commands. first one will obtain a coockie, and return it, and another method will reuse results of the first one.
Something like:

```
// Method to get coockie
Cypress.Commands.add('getCookie', (email, password) => {
  cy.request({
      url: 'xxx',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
          email,
          password,
      }
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    let cookie = response.body.Cookies
    return cookie
    })
})

// Method to get sessionId that will reuse getCoockie method
Cypress.Commands.add('getSession', (email, password) => {
  cy.getCookie(email, password).then(cookie => {
    let session = "SESSIONID=" + cookie.SESSIONID + ";"
    return session
  })
})

// test
describe('test', () => {
  it('bla bla', () => {
    const email = 'test@test.com'
    const pass = 'pass'
    cy.getSession(email, pass).then(session => {
      console.log(session)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: so, you gave me a good path to chase. I did it a little differently though; I re-used the getSession command in one of the other custom commands (they always need a session, so it's killing two birds with one stone) I call in the test,  and it's working now.